How can I execute C# code using Roslyn from a string and use global variables from a Dictionary<string, object>?
I'm working on a C# application where I need to execute C# code provided as a string input using Roslyn. The challenge is to execute this code and access global variables stored in a Dictionary<string, object>. The variables are dynamic, depending on the user's input.
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var variables = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "x", 10 },
        { "y", 20 },
        { "message", "Hello, Roslyn!" }
    };

    string script = @"
        var result = x + y; 
        $""{message} Result: {result}"";
    ";

    // Options de script
    var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(
        typeof(object).Assembly
    );

    var globals = new Globals { Variables = variables };

    try
    {
        var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>(
            script,
            options,
            globals
        );

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (CompilationErrorException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Erreur de compilation :");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ex.Diagnostics));
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

I'm passing the globals object, but I'm getting the following compilation errors:
Erreur de compilation :
(2,26): error CS0103: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context
(2,30): error CS0103: The name 'y' does not exist in the current context
(3,16): error CS0103: The name 'message' does not exist in the current context
(3,13): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

These errors indicate that the script cannot find the variables x, y, and message, even though they are in the Dictionary. How can I correctly pass these dynamic global variables to the script?
NB : the variables used in the script can be at any type, JOBJECT DataTables...

Let's break down your compilation error into two issues:
(2,26): error CS0103: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context
(2,30): error CS0103: The name 'y' does not exist in the current context
(3,16): error CS0103: The name 'message' does not exist in the current context

For these errors this is because you just defined a Dictionary named Variables in your custom Globals class. That's why when your script is being executed there are no x or y could be found as they are stored inside Variables dictionary.
To fix it you need to access them as key-value pair:
string script = @"
    var result = (int)Variables[""x""] + (int)Variables[""y""]; 
    $""{message} Result: {result}"";
";

Remember to cast it back to int otherwise it will throw as you store the values in dictionary as object:
(2,22): error CS0019: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object'

Then the other issue:
(3,13): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

This is because of you just created a string literal without doing anything in your script:
$""{message} Result: {result}"";

To fix this, and I am assuming you are trying to print the result, change your script to:
Console.WriteLine($""{Variables[""message""]} Result: {result}"");

You will need to add the import to have Console.WriteLine() works:
var options = ScriptOptions.Default
.AddReferences(typeof(object).Assembly)
.AddImports("System"); // <- Here

Otherwise it will throw the following:
(3,9): error CS0103: The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context

The complete code will be as follow:
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;

var variables = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "x", 10 },
        { "y", 20 },
        { "message", "Hello, Roslyn!" }
    };

string script = @"
        var result = (int)Variables[""x""] + (int)Variables[""y""]; 
        Console.WriteLine($""{Variables[""message""]} Result: {result}"");
";

// Options de script
var options = ScriptOptions.Default
.AddReferences(typeof(object).Assembly)
.AddImports("System");

var globals = new Globals() { Variables = variables };

try
{
    var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>(
        script,
        options,
        globals
    );

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (CompilationErrorException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Erreur de compilation :");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ex.Diagnostics));
}
Console.ReadLine();


public class Globals
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Variables { get; set; }
}

And the output when execute:
Hello, Roslyn! Result: 30

Reference: dotnet/roslyn GitHub Repository Scripting-API-Samples
EDIT:
If the value of x and y and message is fixed, you can do the following to keep user input simple:
string preprocessing = @"
    var x = (int)Variables[""x""];
    var y = (int)Variables[""y""];
";
string script = @"
    var result = x + y; 
    Console.WriteLine($""{Variables[""message""]} Result: {result}"");
";
var builder = new StringBuilder(preprocessing);
builder.Append(script);
//...
var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>(
    builder.ToString(),
    options,
    globals
);


Hey Ferry,
thank you for your infos, but my main problem is how to keep our input : script, simple. For the user it should be only " x = y + 10;" as script, and the number of variables is dynamic, and i may have diffrente type of variables for exemple : "x = obj.age + 3;"  obj is just an Object in our dictionary, i may have a DataRow or JObject..

Hi @Youchenn I have updated the answer, see if it works?
